# How to create Repository for MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb

Repository for MongoDB. but I don't want to create connection and Collection in constructor, need separate method like we can use Using statement.

```cs
Using(var context = MongDbContext().Create()){

}
```

may I get any help on this

Comment: have a look at this example [asp.net web-api project](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB-Entities-Repository-Pattern). might help you get an idea.

Comment: Thanks for the reference but could you help me to have a repository with Create connection and Database inside Repository class ?